# the meaning and grammar of 'borrow' in this sentence

Tags: grammar, difference

These are the sentences:

> My umbrella  **is borrowed** by Tom. May I use yours？
>
> My umbrella  **has been borrowed** by Tom. May I use yours?

What is the difference in these two sentences?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> My umbrella is borrowed by Tom.

is something that I can't imagine a native English speaker saying, except *maybe* if we are describing a play or a comedy sketch that we perform repeatedly - the use of the present simple is usually for timeless or habitual actions. And even in this meaning, I would expect *gets borrowed*. Either way, it does not fit with the following *May I use yours*.

> My umbrella has been borrowed by Tom.

uses the present perfect, and indicates that the action happened in the past, and has present relevance. By far the most likely present relevance is that he still has it. This would be the most natural and obvious way to say this (apart from the far more natural choice of the active "Tom has borrowed my umbrella").

Answer (score 0):

> My umbrella is borrowed by Tom. May I use yours？

My umbrella is *currently* in Tom's possession, right now.

> My umbrella has been borrowed by Tom. May I use yours?

At *some ambiguous point in the past*, my umbrella has been in Tom's possession.

Note that I'm making no *explicit* claim as to its *current* location, but since I'm asking to use yours, I'm *implying* he still has it.